# Combine strings in C++ to rename a file to present date

Tags: c++, string, time

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to write a small program that will take a .txt file from my desktop, sort it in a folder and rename it to current date.
My idea is in combining three strings, first string is a direction to the main directory where I want to move the file, second string is the name of the month in my native language and the third string is the string that represents the date in dd-mm.txt format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int result;
    std::time_t t = std::time(0);
    std::tm* now = std::localtime(&t);
    char date_string[100];
    strftime(date_string, 50, "\\%e-%m.txt", now);
    string mnths[12] = { "Januar", "Februar","Mart","April","Maj","Jun","Jul","Avgust","Septembar","Oktobar","Novembar","Decembar" };

    char strt[] = "C:\\Users\\B\\Desktop\\New.txt";
    char fnsh[] = "C:\\Users\\B\\Desktop\\Journal\\2020\\"+ mnths[date_string[month]]+ date_string;

    result = rename(strt, fnsh);
    if (result == 0)
        puts("File successfully renamed");
    else
        perror("Error renaming file");
    return 0;
};
```

For the second string, in case of April for example, I want to get the fourth value in the mnths array. I've tried a mishmash of solutions looking up online but now I'm lost and need help. Most notable error is "Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type" and I've googled it but I still can't understand completely how it relates to my problem and how I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: `char fnsh[]` is your problem. If you used a `std::string` you could concatenate the string using +

Comment: `mnths[]` is an array of `std::string` objects. The result of concat'ing a `std::string` with a `char[]`/`char*` is another `std::string`, which you are then trying to assign to a `char[]`. That will not work. Change `strt` and `fnsh` to `std::string` and use their `c_str()` methods when passing them to `rename()`. Also, where is `month` in `date_string[month]` defined? `date_string[month]` doesn't even look like the right value you should be using to index into the `mnths[]` array to begin with. Perhaps you meant `now->tm_mon` instead?

Comment: There's no practical limit to the length of variable names, so please don't shorten them needlessly. Use semantically and descriptive names for your variables. Removing vowels just makes your code less understandable (especially since you're not doing it consistently).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alright, some of this seems intuitive and I've changed fnsh, strt and date_string to std::string however i seem to come to a problem in strftime function where date_string can't be used as it's const char* and not char*(after trying to use the c_str method on it). Also the date_string[month] is just something I placed as I didn't know how to approach to solving that but now->tm_mon works good.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you, as I mentioned it's basically a mishmash of different code I've picked up around the internet and I haven't gotten around to adjusting it to be more coherent, but thank you for your advice.

Comment: @BorkoP I didn't say to change `date_string` to a `std::string`. It wants a `char[]` buffer to write into. If you want to use a `std::string` for that buffer, then you would need to presize it first and then pass its data pointer to `strftime()`, eg: `string date_string(100, '\0'); date_string.resize(strftime(&date_string[0], 50, "\\%e-%m.txt", now));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your advices, this seems to work as intended now. I actually have a book I picked up at a local library but it was confusing at first so I tried to throw myself into the fire by working on a person project, which turned out great with languages like python. Seems like I definitely need a deeper understanding here so I'll check out the link you sent. Thank you again.